# how to use a variable from another function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, function

This is a basic version of my function (first time I am doing this, so I'm sorry if I don't explain it well)

```
var pages = {
    init:function(){

    },
    home:function(){

        articleid = this.closest("article").attr('id');
        skillsbtn =  $(this).hasClass("skillsbt");
        home = $('#home');
        homeheight = '-' + home.height();

    if (skillsbtn && articleid == "home"){
        home.animate({"marginTop"   : homeheight},800);
    }
},
    work:function(){
//same variables are requred here: skillsbtn =  $(this).hasClass("skillsbt");...
    },
    skills:function(){
//same variables are requred here: skillsbtn =  $(this).hasClass("skillsbt");...
    },
    contact:function(){

    },
}
```

So the idea is skillsbtn =  `$(this)` refer to whatever `$(this)` is at `home:function`. I have tried to duplicate the variables from `home:function` to `work:function` and it wokeded fine. But can I put the variable I need in the `init:function` but be able to call them within the `home:function` and by doing so, be able to change what ever `$(this)` is, to mean this->home, or this->work

I have tried to access it like `pages.init.skillsbtn.call(this)` but it dies not work.

Hope you can help
- Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use global variables all over (where is the `var` before each of the leading four assignments in `home` function)?

You want to share state and you do not use objects for this? That's what they are for.
What is pages? If it is some kind of 'repository' or 'namespace', maybe use UpperCase name to distinguish it is not the plain instance.

Since `this` in jQuery events is bound to the source of the event, you cannot use `this` plainly, but you can do this:

```
var Pages = {
    init:function(){
      Pages.worker = new PagesWorker;
      // later if you see fit you can have more of these
    },
    home:function(){
      return Pages.worker.home($(this));
    },
    work:function(){
      return Pages.worker.work($(this));
    },
    skills:function(){
      return Pages.worker.skills($(this));
    },
    contact:function(){
      return Pages.worker.contact($(this));
    },
}

function PagesWorker(src){
  // init
}

PagesWorker.prototype.home = function(src){

    // use var xxx = yyy for ones local for this function only
    // use this.xxx = yyy for those that should persist between functions   
    var articleid = src.closest("article").attr('id');
    this.skillsbtn =  src.hasClass("skillsbt");
    var home = $('#home');
    var homeheight = '-' + home.height();

    if (this.skillsbtn && articleid == "home"){
        home.animate({"marginTop"   : homeheight},800);
    }
};

PagesWorker.prototype.work = function(src){
  //same variables are requred here: skillsbtn etc.
  //no problem, use this.skillsbtn etc.
};

PagesWorker.prototype.skills = function(src){
  //same variables are requred here: skillsbtn etc.
  //no problem, use this.skillsbtn etc.
};

PagesWorker.prototype.contact = function(src){
  //same variables are requred here: skillsbtn etc.
  //no problem, use this.skillsbtn etc.
};
```

If you are *really* sure you will only have one pages object, you can use pages.xxx to share variables between function calls and your original code. But that is not the right thing to do unless you are really, really sure.

Comment: can all this (programming) be learned by practice and tutorials or do I need to read any background information? in order to become good at this

Comment: I'd say practice is not enough, without some sort of guidance you learn lot of 'hacking' and 'shortcuts'. The copy-paste-modify works if you know what you want, but less as a long-time learning. You should read some books, or good blogs (I don't know of good ones for beginner, though; I feel good at www.c2.com or www.martinfowler.com but these are more about higher level - but after all, design is what is important, the program (and language to write it) is just an implementation - if your design is bad, even Smalltalk won't help you do it right).

Answer (score 1):

Create another object which contains the variables you require to be in global scope and use it as a repository. Try this:

```
var pages = {
    init: function() {
    },
    settings: {
        skillsButton: "test"
    },
    home: function() {
        this.settings.skillsButton = "value changed in 'home'";
    }
}
```

You can then refer to `settings.skillsButton` wherever you require it.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/PaUEC/)

Comment: He will have a problem here because as I see it `this` refers to a DOM element in his code.

Answer (score 0):

Make the variable global by declaring it outside the function and assigning it inside the function

```
var globalVar,
    pages = {
    init:function(){

    },
    home:function(){

        articleid = this.closest("article").attr('id');
        skillsbtn =  $(this).hasClass("skillsbt");
        home = $('#home');
        homeheight = '-' + home.height();

    if (skillsbtn && articleid == "home"){
        home.animate({"marginTop"   : homeheight},800);
    }
},
    work:function(){
//same variables are requred here: skillsbtn =  $(this).hasClass("skillsbt");...
    },
    skills:function(){
//same variables are requred here: skillsbtn =  $(this).hasClass("skillsbt");...
    },
    contact:function(){

    },
}
```

Then assign whatever you want to use to the global variable